# How can I see how many pts "singlespace" is?

Tags: luatex, memoir, line-spacing

I'm trying to typeset in 10/12pt in lualatex. How can I figure out if single spacing (`\SingleSpacing` in memoir) is according to this specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\typeout {%
  Fontsize: \f@size pt / Baselineskip: \the\baselineskip
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

This will show

```
Fontsize: 10pt / Baselineskip: 12.0pt
```

showing that 10/12pt is the default in memoir. You can easily add `\SingleSpacing` or similar commands to see the effect they have on the sizes.